# Asp.Net Identity Two Factor Cookie not working after Azure Swap

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity

I'm using Asp.Net 2FA and deployed on Azure. I have it working as per the sample Identity 2.1 projects.
When I login, I can select to Remember browser and the system sends a cookie - called .AspNet.TwoFactorCookie. On subsequent logins, then I don't need to enter the 2FA code. All good.

But on a new deployment, I deploy to the staging area on Azure, and then do a Swap, swapping the production and staging environments. If I then try to login, the .AspNet.TwoFactorCookie no longer works, and I need to get a new 2FA code.

However, if I swap again, ie so production is back to what it was, the .AspNet.TwoFactorCookie works again.

It would appear that in decrypting the cookie, the value returned from production and staging environments is different. But how can I work around this? For minimal down time of the production environment, the Azure swap is the way to go, but then it breaks the 2FA authentication.

Comment: Do you have a machineKey element defined in your web.config?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `machineKey` to your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

As @ojf and @trailmax said, I just needed the machineKey in the web.config

For anyone else, [here's a site to generate a machineKey](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/) and you just need to add it to your web.config under the  section. (Thanks guys)